# Traduction de « this » dans « We believe that this is the first work that shows how... »

Tags: traduction, anglais, démonstratifs

> We believe that **this** is the first work that shows how...

A/

> Nous pensons que **c’est** le premier travail qui montre comment...

B/

> Nous pensons que **cela** est le premier travail qui montre comment...

C/

> Nous pensons que **ce travail** est le premier qui montre comment...

Dans ce contexte quelle tournure rend *this* ?

Comment: Est-ce que « this » renvoie au document en question lui-même ou à un autre ouvrage qui a été cité ?

Comment: Ce n'est vraiment pas une question de traduction. Il n'y a aucune raison de citer la formulation anglaise qui n'a rien d'exceptionnel. Ce serait mieux d'expliquer ce que tu cherches à écrire directement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Une autre suggestion :

> Nous pensons qu'il s'agit là du premier travail qui montre que...

*Travail* n'est probablement pas la meilleure traduction de *work* ici. On trouvera plutôt :

> ...la première étude qui montre que...
>
> ...la première recherche qui montre que...
>
> ...la première publication qui montre que...

etc.

Answer (score 2):

A nécessite un antécédent. B : 'ceci' ('this') plutôt que 'cela' ('that'). C : correct mais moins littéral.